# Replace Picture Source (Adding)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i wish to do is have a div containing a image, when a button/mini picture is pressed the image's source will change from 1-2 2-3, etc adding 1 each time. This needs to go both ways:
i.e Right Arrow: 1.jpg 2.jpg Left Arrow 3.jpg 2.jpg Now the script also needs to include a IF statement so if the picture doesn't exist the button will be visibility: hidden; in css. Something like IF picture source 5.jpg + 1 doesn't exist #mini img visibility: hidden;
Currently i had an idea i could use something not the same but similar to this (jQuery). I used this script previously to change a image on hover, i figure i could change it onclick and use something similar.

```
$(function() { $('#buttons #right img').each(function() {
var originalSrc = this.src,
   hoverSrc = originalSrc.replace(/\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/, '_over.$1'); 
   image = new Image();

image.src = hoverSrc;

$(this).hover(function() {
  image.onload = function() {
}
  this.src = hoverSrc;
}, function() {
   this.src = originalSrc;
});
});
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really hard

the image supports an onerror so simply load the image onclick and onload replace the source

```
var currentImage;    
function loadImage(img,dir) {
  currentImage = document.getElementById(img);
  var currentNumber = parseInt(currentImage.src.split("gallery/")[1]); // get the number
  var newNumber = currentNumber + (dir===1)?1:-1;
  var testImage = new Image();
  testImage.onload=function() {
    currentImage.src=this.src;  
    currentImage.style.visibility='visible'   
  }
  testImage.onerror=function() {
    currentImage.style.visibility='hidden'   
  } 
  testImage.src="gallery/"+newNumber+".jpg";
  return false;
}


<img id="image1" src="gallery/1.jpg" />
<a href="#" onclick="return loadImage('image1',-1)" title="prev"><img src="prev.gif" border="0" /></a>    <a href="#" onclick="return loadImage('image1',1)" title="next"><img src="next.gif" border="0" /></a>
```

Update: jQuery version: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8FB5z/2/

Comment: Is this easy to do in jQuery? Do you know how?

Comment: I guess I could figure out how to do it in jQuery. Right now I need to be somewhere. There will likely be many jQuery experts awake later today. If not, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @mplungjan Ok :) I will wait then.

Comment: @mplungjan Just realised there is one slight problem. Naturally i dont want all my images just sitting in the root folder i want them in /gallery, so my first image will src will be gallery/1.jpg

Comment: @mplungjan Just testing the script before i vote/accept your answer

Comment: @mplungjan Doesn't seem to work http://58.106.14.233/~Jason/Yoga%20Health/gallery.php

Comment: @Jason. found a bug. It does not update the number in the image if it is hidden. I need to just show the image if it was hidden :http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8FB5z/2/